# TextView change to ImageView on same ButtonClick- uncompleted

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-button

I have a button. In onClick() it will show TextView and ImageView at the same time, with the same outcome.But I am facing a problem, the image doesn't load completely. Can anyone tell me why is it so? Thanks in advance!

Code for Button onClick

```
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override     
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch(count){
            case 0 :
                    df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                            "fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf"); 
                    ConvertToBitmap();
                 break;
            case 1:
                    df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                            "fonts/code128.ttf");
                    ConvertToBitmap();
                    break;
            case 2: 
                    df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                        "fonts/Molot.otf");
                    ConvertToBitmap();
                break;
            case 3:
                    df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                        "fonts/Days.otf");
                    ConvertToBitmap();
                break;
            case 4:
                    df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                        "fonts/Paranoid.otf");
                    ConvertToBitmap();
                break;

            }
        }

    });
```

Code for TextView and ImageView

```
public void ConvertToBitmap(){
        if (et.getText().toString().equals("")) {

            //Clear textView
            tv.setText("");          
            et.setText("");
            tv.buildDrawingCache();
            iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

        }
        else { 
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1.setTypeface(df);

            String editTextValue = et.getText().toString();            
            tv.setText(editTextValue);

            tv.buildDrawingCache();
            bmap = tv.getDrawingCache();
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmap);


        }
    }
```

**EDITED!**
Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gameScreen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"

android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.example.textdrawn3.Text
    android:id="@+id/textDrawn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.11" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#0000cd"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Image"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/fonts_spinner"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:context=".TextDrawn3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:hint="text"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e6e6fa"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does it look like?  If your save to storage function is working, is the image its saving look like what you expect or like what's on screen?

Comment: So sorry I should had taken out the code for save bitmap to SD card.. Right now is when I convert it to bitmap from TextView and put inside imageview, the imageview is only showing half of the textview. why is it so?

Comment: Mind posting your layout xml?  The answer is probably there

Comment: I have posted my layout xml above. =D

Comment: I suspect that the layout weights are the problem.  You have an item above that's set to a fixed height but has a layout weight of 4x the image's weight.  That means the image is only going to be 1/4 the size.  Or at least I think thats how it would work, I've never used weights and exact sizes in combination before.  If you really want it to be that size, set the scaleType of the image to fitCenter or something else that scales the image.

Comment: Erm.. I had tried to take out all the weight in the layout but however the outcome still the same.Is it something I had done wrong in the code?

Comment: It may be autoscaling the bitmap.  Try adding the scale type to the image, force it to scale to the size of your view.

Comment: thx for your help, I tried another way by saving the bitmap and load it again on the customview, It works!